# wmd model gensim is returning infinity

Tags: python, model, artificial-intelligence, word2vec, wmd

I am trying to calculate the wmd distance amongst the below 2 vectors and the result I am receiving is **Infinity**.
I even tried just checking for word 'django' and 'django' and even then it returns inf (Infinity).

Can anyone suggest a better trained model for technical skills?

```
>>> import gensim.downloader as API
>>> model = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')

>>> distance = model.wmdistance(["kafka"], ["django","pip","conda","python","django","java","springboot","rest","microservices","microservices","reddis","kafka","consumer","publisher","spark","storm","rabbitmq","customer", "service","eventbus","service","aws","aws" "cli","azure","google","cloud","shell","bash","script","config","lambda"])

>>> distance                                                                                                                         inf
```

Comment: When I am doing the below, then again the issue is same 

>>> distance = model.wmdistance(["django"], ["django"])
>>> distance 
inf

Comment: Are you using the latest Gensim, 4.0.1? This resembles a bug that was purportedly fixed a while ago – https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/979 – so the 1st thing to check is if you see the same thing in a current version.